# Grafana Alias By Template Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I'm trying to figure out how to display multiple values of a template variable in a graph.

The values for my template variable $bidtype are A to J.

Right now I solved the problem by duplicating the queries and changing the value and alias in each, but ideally I wanted something like this:

campaignId:AAA AND customVariable10:$bidtype alias by $bidtype

Here is the screenshot of what I have now, any suggestions please?

[image: My Grafana dasahboard]

Answer (score 0):

I found how to separate into multiple lines with just one query, the trick is to use **Group By**

[image]